# Looking up times in DB based off actual time or actual time including Delay

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I am looking for a way to be able to grab rows from a database from a time.

Two columns exist:
Time - scheduled Time
Delay - +seconds that time is delayed.

Let's say:

```
ID,time,delay
1,18:23,360
2,18:25,0
3,17:15,-60
```

Now, let's say I am searching for buses after actually arriving at/after 18:25, how would i do it to include these two results:

```
2,18:25,0
1,18:23,360 (note: 18:23 + 360 seconds  = 18:29)
```

in a query like

```
where `time` >= '18:23'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE DATE_ADD(Time,INTERVAL TimeDelay SECOND) >= '18:25:00'
```

[MySql Date_Add Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

Comment: Ok thanks, I do have issues. does the `time` column have to be set in a certain specific way to work

Comment: Time should be a DateTIme, but the function should handle that or even an nvarchar/varchar [Addtional documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)